# Google android maps v2 MetersToEquatorPixel

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am currently tasked with converting a Google Android maps v1 application over to Google Android Maps V2 application. The process is not a pleasant one (thanks google).

My problem is that in the previous application they used a nice little method of Google Android Maps v1 called **metersToEquatorPixels** that you could get from the Map's projection object.i.e.

```
int px =(int) (mapProjection.metersToEquatorPixels(radiusInMeters) * (1 / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitudeActual))));
```

However, in Google Android maps V2 there is not such a method I could find. Can anyone tell me where it is, or what a suitable replacement might be?

Comment: Please let me know, How you got radius in meters value. I want to set radius as per 150 meters.

Comment: @vabhi vab I think you might need to be a little more specific, radius of what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to do that, just draw a circle and pass away center and radius in meters

```
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(latLng)
     .radius(radiusInMeters)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: You are correct. It seems that Google maps V2 does not need this conversion method anymore because the measurement units are more uniform across all commands and features.