# Radius in meters to pixels for drawing circle on Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw zones/coverage areas on map in form of circle. Now first I draw circle from this [tutorial](http://toastdroid.com/2014/05/27/google-maps-with-custom-view-overlays/) I implemented all same code from that tutorial. Now I draw a circle of radius 150 meter but I came to know that I have to change that 150m to some other unit may be pixel which gives me actual radius on which circle should be drawn . For this I went through number of sites some advised to use **metersToEquatorPixels**- which is not in Google map V2 and other methods but they are not giving solution from where I can sure that is the correct radius to draw on Map. More over come says radius will be calculate according to zoomLevel/scale. I tried all methods which was giving on internet but did not get success.
Any will be appreciated.

[I need circle under which map can move but not the circle](http://giant.gfycat.com/ShyAlarmingBoubou.gif)

Comment: Related: [Google android maps v2 MetersToEquatorPixel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071133/google-android-maps-v2-meterstoequatorpixel) and it suggests to use the `addCircle()` method which   takes the radius in meters.

Comment: I already used that but it gives fixed effect means if I drag or move map ,circle will also move and will be fixed. I added a link in my question , that same functionality I want to add for that I have to use custom layer to draw circle

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737054/how-can-i-draw-a-static-target-circle-on-google-maps/35751087#35751087